# Android Widget: Center a square image with variable size and place text in it

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm trying since hours to find a solution. I have a Android Home Screen Widget which consists of a background image (square) and some text, which needs to be in the bottom left of the square.

Unfortunately the home screen rasters are not a square, but can behigher than wider. Also the widget should adapt to the size defined (resized) by the user.

So I need to center a square image vertically, while resizing it to the maximum square width and place the text on the bottom of the square.

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg2Rn.png)

With ConstraintLayout that would be easy, but ConstraintLayout  is not supported in Widgets. And I also can't use Java code, since I cant get any height / width information via the RemoteViews.

Resizing and centering the image is quite easy, since I could just use         layout_width / layout_height = match_parent for the image and the layout. But how can I now place the text at the left bottom of the image?

Tried RelativeLayout, FrameLayout, but could not get anywhere close.

Comment: What if just set layout_width and layout_height of TextView MATCH_PARENT also, and set gravity="bottom|left" to the same TextView ? @Thomas D

Comment: @Rob, than the text would be at the bottom of the red lines, but not within the square picture :-(

Comment: try to use imageView with wrap content height, in relative layout and align text bottom to the bottom of image view

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_widget"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_text"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image_view"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have created sample widget and as you can see in a relative layout it works ok - you can manipulate the layout as you want, here is how the widget looks in xml code

[image]

and here are widget on the emulator with different sizes
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Rob, Thanks a lot! But the image needs to be a square, it can't be cropped or "filled" to fit the space. The image width needs to be same as the height. So if the available space is a rectangle and higher than wider, the top and bottom needs to be empty and the square image in the vertical middle. If the rectangle is more wide than high, the left and right sides must be empty and the image in the horizontal center. You can think of it like an App icon, with a dynamic text on it.

Comment: You can control that from XML file that you configure the widget with, you can make the widget always square, you can control it with also with your layout xml just need to play with it 2-3 times

Comment: For example you can try with frameLayout(relative layout (image view, text view) hierarchy and manage your relative layout sizes like you are doing currently with imag view